Using window objects to define javascript variables for Chrome extension
I am trying to create a dynamic overlay for a browser game that will update team information as it updates within the game. The function that is used in the game to do so is:
updateGameInfo()

I have the HTML/CSS/JS defined, so for team member name, it would be
const memberName = document.getElementById("name")

And I would like to change it after updateGameInfo() is complete to be
memberName.textContent = window.gameInfo.party[0].name

How can I create this function to automatically run after updateGameInfo() and get the relevant information to change the variables?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you're looking to automatically update the overlay after the updateGameInfo() function finishes, there are a few friendly approaches you can consider! It all depends on how updateGameInfo() is set up and whether you can tweak it a bit. Here are some options to help you out:

Add a Callback in updateGameInfo()

If you can modify the updateGameInfo() function, adding a callback is a great option! Here’s a simple example:
function updateGameInfo(callback) {
    // Your game update logic goes here

    // Once the game info is updated, call the callback
    if (callback) callback();
}

// Use it like this:
updateGameInfo(() => {
    const memberName = document.getElementById("name");
    memberName.textContent = window.gameInfo.party[0].name;
});


Use MutationObserver to Observe Changes

If modifying updateGameInfo() isn’t an option, you can use a MutationObserver to keep an eye on changes in the DOM where the game information resides. This way, your overlay will update whenever necessary! Here’s how:
const memberName = document.getElementById("name");

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    memberName.textContent = window.gameInfo.party[0].name;
});

// Assume game info is stored in an element with ID "game-info"
const gameInfoElement = document.getElementById("game-info");

// Start observing for any changes in child nodes or the subtree
observer.observe(gameInfoElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });


Set an Interval Check as a Fallback

If all else fails, using setInterval to check for updates every now and then can work too! Here’s a simple way to do that:
setInterval(() => {
    if (window.gameInfo && window.gameInfo.party[0]) {
        const memberName = document.getElementById("name");
        memberName.textContent = window.gameInfo.party[0].name;
    }
}, 1000); // Checks every second
``


Thank you so much for the detailed answer! A couple of questions. First, how would I go about finding the Id of the gameInfoElement described in Option 2? I've tried a few console commands but coming up blank.
Then, I added the setInterval() command to script.js (not background.js) and it didn't seem to update. Did I add it to the wrong location?

To find the ID, try console.log(window.gameInfo); or document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(el => {
if (el.textContent.includes("unique game text")) console.log(el);
});.  For setInterval(), ensure it’s in window.onload: window.onload = function() {
setInterval(() => {
if (window.gameInfo?.party[0]) {
document.getElementById("name").textContent = window.gameInfo.party[0].name;
}
}, 1000);
};. Hope that helps...
